# How do I properly read large text files in Python so I dont clog up memory?

Tags: python, file, large-files

So today while buying BTC I messed up and lost my decryption passphrase to wallet that ATM sends automatically on email.

I remember the last 4 characters of the passphrase so I generated a wordlist and wanted to try to bruteforce my way into it. It was a 4MB file and the script checked all the possibilities with no luck. Then I realized that maybe the letters are wrong, but I still remember what numbers were in those 4 chars. Well suddenly, I have 2GB file that get SIGKILLed by Ubuntu.

Here is the whole code, it is very short.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from zipfile import ZipFile
import sys
i = 0
found = False

with ZipFile("/home/kuskus/Desktop/wallet.zip") as zf:
    with open('/home/kuskus/Desktop/wl.txt') as wordlist:
        for line in wordlist.readlines():
            if(not found):
                try:
                    zf.extractall(pwd = str.encode(line))
                    print("password found: %s" % line)
                    found = True
                except:
                    print(i)
                    i += 1
            else: sys.exit()
```

I think the issue is that the textfile fills up the memory so OS kills it. I really don't know how could I read the file, maybe by 1000 lines, then clean it and do another 1000 lines. If anyone could help me I would be very grateful, thank you in advance :) Oh and the text file has about 300 milion lines, if it matters.

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: `readlines()` creates a list out of the file, so the whole file will be in memory. If you change that to  `for line in wordlist` only one line of the file will be loaded into memory at a time.

Comment: Only 4GB. Without creating the list it works like a charm. Now I hope It is gonna find it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually the best thing to do is to iterate over the file directly. The file handler will act as a generator, producing lines one at a time rather than aggregating them all into memory at once into a list (as `fh.readlines()` does):

```py
with open("somefile") as fh:
     for line in fh:
         # do something
```

Furthermore, file handles allow you to read specific amounts of data if you so choose:

```py
with open("somefile") as fh:
    number_of_chars = fh.read(15) # 15 is the number of characters in a StringIO style handler
    while number_of_chars:
        # do something with number_of_chars
        number_of_chars = fh.read(15)
```

Or, if you want to read a specific number of lines:

```py
with open('somefile') as fh:
    while True:
        chunk_of_lines = [fh.readline() for i in range(5)] # this will read 5 lines at a time
        if not chunk_of_lines:
            break
        # do something else here
```

Where `fh.readline()` is analogous to calling `next(fh)` in a for loop.

The reason a `while` loop is used in the latter two examples is because once the file has been completely iterated through, `fh.readline()` or `fh.read(some_integer)` will yield an empty string, which acts as `False` and will terminate the loop